# Interactive python input() for IoTEdge Module

Tags: python, docker, interactive, eof, azure-iot-edge

I am new to python and I inherited some code that requires keyboard input by the user. When turning this into a docker container, I can easily run it locally with "-it" flag to take in my input and avoid EOF errors.

```
while True:
  key = input("Please enter:\n")
        if key == "q":
            break
        if key == "t":
           #do something
```

However, the code needs to run as an **IoT Edge Module** on an IoT Edge Device on Azure IoT Hub, and there doesn't seem to be an equivalent option to the "-it" flag for that. When I run the code without changes as IoT Edge Module, I get EOF errors and it breaks on the "input" line.

**How can I change my code to achieve the following requirements when running as IoT Edge Module?**

1. code can receive interactive input from the user
2. code WAITS for this input (no matter how long it takes) without breaking

I am considering looking into messaging and async/await, however this is only for testing and not production code, so I am wondering if that is overkill and there is maybe some simpler workaround to achieve what I want?

As a basic workaround, I tried to have the code check for a file, that I then manually created in the docker container, however for some reason when I did that, it never went into the if-condition, but instead left the loop

```
   while True:
        if os.path.isfile(break_file_path):
            break
        if os.path.isfile(trigger_file_path):
           #do something
   #do something else
```

When creating the file at trigger_file_path, it never does "something", but immediately goes to "something else".

I also learned from this, that I can only see the logs in the IoTHub after the while-loop is done, which is bad for some code that should potentially be able to wait arbitrary long for input.

I would appreciate input on any of these points. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the input. I tried the env variables, but did not get that to work. The code didn't find the env variables I created inside the docker container and restarting the docker container with new env variables was not what I wanted.

I realized however that my original work-around with the files worked just fine. I just had mixed up the variables for triggerfile and breakfile in the IoT Edge Module setup... so creating the triggerfile lead to breaking. Once that was fixed, it worked like a charm. :)